# How Do I compile SQLite with the TCL Bindings?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I am trying to update to the latest version of SQLite and when sourcing the package I get error.  `couldn't find procedure Sqlite3_Init`

The version of SQLite that I had before was installed using teacup.

I have tried to follow the steps but I have never really compiled anything really, Any help would be appreciated!

tried compiling [`sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz`](https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right download. The Tcl extension is in the `tea` folder inside there; the `README` in that directory has instructions for what to do.

Alternatively, full source distributions of Tcl 8.6 also include SQLite along with a few other extensions (though there's a cut-down source distribution that doesn't).

Comment: Thanks @Donal Ill give that a try.